The derivative of a function's Fourier Series is not the derivative of the function?
I am interested in the function $\frac{z}{e^z+1}$. Its Fourier Series is $$\frac{z}{e^z-1}=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{t}{e^t-1}dt+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(cos(kz)\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{tcos(kt)}{e^t-1}dt+sin(kz)\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{tsin(kt)}{e^t-1}dt), -\pi<z<\pi$$ Therefore, $$\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-ksin(kz)\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{tcos(kt)}{e^t-1}dt+kcos(kz)\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{tsin(kt)}{e^t-1}dt), -\pi<z<\pi$$ The first equation works perfectly over the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. However, calculating the second series with Wolfram Cloud gives me $\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ shifted up by exactly 0.5 (approximation was to 200 terms). Besides the y-shift, the overall shape of the function was correct, but I  don't really know what's going on here. I feel so close, yet so far.
